# Embed ruby in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby

I want to hide some map if the event is not triggered. 
If the event is triggered then render the map.
Code below:

```
- if cookie_law_enabled
  :javascript
    document.addEventListener('cl:ready', function() {
      = render partial: '_reusable/map' 
    })
```

But it doesn't work. Probably because " = render partial: '_reusable/map' " is not right embedded in javascript.

Can somebody show me a better way to embed it.

Comment: Please, before someone vote me down, tell me at least what iam doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it, not like this. Possible alternatives:

- render your partial to a hidden div (outside of condition), and in your event handler simply show the div.
- in your event handler, do an ajax request to the server, to get that partial rendered and returned. After you receive the response, you can show it, or whatever needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
= escape_javascript render(:partial => '_reusable/map')
```

or

```
= j render(:partial => '_reusable/map')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You can [render partials with AJAX](https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy), I suggest you google for more information.